# regex get str before str

Tags: regex

how do i get str before specific str?
for example. if i have `lalala lolo xaxaxa lolo` i wan't to find the str before the word `lolo` so => `lalala` and `xaxaxa`.

i got stuck at `\w+(?=\s*<[bad/])`

Comment: `\w+(?=\W+lolo)`?

Comment: @zerkms i was this close haha. Thank you! :)

Comment: You should really add the infortmation about your used language, when asking for Regex-Help. (Sometimes it's different, but most the time there are more native solutions available). For your case there are "perfect" solutions without regex, for example: `stringInstance.split("lolo")` - The resulting array would always contain each part of the string "before" `lolo`. - which would be `["lalala ", " xaxaxa "]`. Depneding on your used language there is a `trim()` command to get rid of whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Either capture just that part:

```
/(\w+)\s*lolo/
```

or, if you need the entire regex to match just the part before lolo, use lookahead:

```
/\w+(?=\s*lolo)/
```

To capture the fourth word after `<chrome>`, you would do:

```
/<chrome>\W*(?:\w+\W+){3}(\w+)/
```

(or possibly `\W+` instead of `\W*`, and possibly `\s` instead of `\W` and `\S` instead of `\w` everywhere.  depends what you want to consider a "word").

Or use lookbehind to match just that word (but lookbehind functionality varies between languages so we'd have to know what language you are using).

Comment: actually thats not what iv'e needed. i need to catch <chrome>  and print the 4th word after it